# Any way to put template class instances which has different template parameters to a vector?

Tags: c++, templates

I got a template class from my colleague, let's say it is:

```
template<int p1>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() : i(p1) {}
 private:
  int i;
};
```

(This is an example, the real class is more complicated, but this example is enough to illustrate my question.)

I don't know if he do this instead of using a constructor parameter on purpose, but now I want to put some foos in a vector:

```
std::vector<Foo<1>> v;
v.push_back(Foo<1>());
v.push_back(Foo<2>());
```

this code will of course not compiled, because `Foo<1>` and `Foo<2>` are two different types. But as a matter of fact, these two types have same memory layout, so is there any way I can manage types like this through a vector?

Edit: I find that he use the `p1` for some compile time check, not that useless, lets despite the discussion of the design, while focusing this question.

Comment: Why does `Foo` need to be a template type at all?   The parameter `p1` is used to initialise the member `i`.   Changing `Foo` to be a non-template class, and providing a constructor that accepts an `int` allows all instances to be the same type - so they CAN be stored in a vector without doing a song and dance - with distinct values as needed.

Comment: On side note if classes share same base layout but have different interfaces, organize them like that. have a base class or a component class an instance stored inside as a member) that contains all data, if interface is irrelevant for container. Store only data-bearing components, have a fabric way to cast them to interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo<1>` and `Foo<2>` are completely unrelated types so can't be stored in the same vector directly.

Depending on your use-case there are various options.

The simplest is to add a non-templated base class to `Foo` then you can create a vector of pointers (preferably smart ones) to the base class which you can then add any `Foo` object to.

Another option is to use `std::variant` but then you need to declare in advance every template that you want to use, if it is many or an arbitrary number this could become cumbersome.

A third option is `std::any`, this will allow you to put anything into your vector. You will then have to check the type of each element before using it though.

Obviously in your simple example the best solution is to remove the template parameter from `Foo` as it serves no purpose.

Comment: does `std::any` have any overheads?

Comment: yes it does, it's similar to `std::variant` that it stores an object plus a tag to state what type it contains. I think `std::variant` is probably faster than `std::any` though. E.g. see https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/any.html#performance-memory-considerations

Comment: @ravenisadesk, `std::any` is allowed to allocate memory on heap to store an object if it is too large to be stored inside `std::any` itself. In contrast, `std::variant` never allocates additional memory.

Answer (score 2):

> But as a matter of fact, these two types have same memory layout, so is there any way I can manage types like this through a vector?

Simply no without any modification to store directly the data into the vector.

You can use a `std::vector<std::variant< Foo<1>, Foo<2>, some more >>` but this will add a tag variable to each element which increases the needed memory resources.

But in general: The template makes really no sense! Having a template type which has a non type template parameter can access this parameter already in compile time. There is no need to store that value again as a run time variable anywhere.

Keep in mind: Each template instance will generate code which is currently not helpful in your example, so your program size increases without any benefit. And it did not save any ram resources, as it copies the parameter into the run time instance.

You definitely should think about your design! Select what you need: run time or compile time! Mixing it as shown in your example wastes only resources.